# Type pattern matching in SML

Tags: sml

I'm doing a simple excercise for a Programming Languages class in SML, the exercise is to compute if a tree is balanced or not. The following code is what I thought would be a valid solution:

```
datatype IntTree = LEAF of int | NODE of (IntTree * IntTree);

fun balanced (LEAF l) = true 
  | balanced (NODE (LEAF l, NODE n)) = false
  | balanced (NODE (NODE n1, NODE n2)) = balanced(n1) andalso balanced(n2)
  | balanced (NODE (NODE n, LEAF l)) = false
  | balanced (NODE (LEAF l1, LEAF l2)) = true;
```

However when I try to run this in the interpreter I get the following error:

```
stdIn:98.42-98.54 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: IntTree
  operand:         IntTree * IntTree
  in expression:
    balanced n1
stdIn:98.63-98.75 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: IntTree
  operand:         IntTree * IntTree
  in expression:
    balanced n2
```

But `NODE` should be of type `IntTree`, why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an SML compiler right now, so I can't test this, but try changing `balanced(n1)` to `(balanced (NODE n1))` (same with `balanced(n2))`.